# Fix poor quality when using WMTS to import Mapbox to QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapbox, mapbox-studio

I have a basemap created using Mapbox and have imported it in to QGIS using WMTS. The quality is terribly pixelated on the map and is just as bad when I try export as an image.

Screenshot:
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Can you give use some details about the WMTS tilematrix and the level you have zoomed in to

Comment: Hi Ian,

It happens at all zoom levels.

What exactly do you mean by the details about the WMTS tilematrix? (Sorry - GIS is not my first language!)

Thanks

Comment: can you add the details of the layer you are adding - what SRS, resolutions/zoom levels it available at etc.